# Dell 3543 Kubuntu 16.04 can't get output to 2nd monitor on HDMI

Tags: kubuntu, dell, 16.04, inspiron, multiple-monitors

This worked with much fiddling on 15.10, but since upgrading to 16.04, I can't get the 2nd monitor working at all.

```
xrandr -q
```

Reports "HDMI1 disconnected" though it isn't.

With open source drivers, only the primary notebook monitor works, and with nVidia proprietary drivers, X can't boot at all.

Maybe a good config of xorg.conf could fix it, but I'm no expert at that. Anyway, has anybody found a fix for Dell 3543, or does anyone at least have some clue where to begin fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

Further investigation revealed that in kernel 4.4, i915 driver has a regression... It's not fixed yet, but this workaround is good:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

edit

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=\"Linux\" video=HDMI-A-1:e"
```

(video=HDMI-A-1:e being the workaround...) And don't forget to

```
sudo update-grub2
```

After reboot, HDMI port is visible to the system, and 2nd monitor works.