# Kubuntu 16.04 Lost Dual Monitor Capability

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

I installed Kubuntu 16.04 on Desktop with add-on Radeon HD 5850 GPU. I'd previously used this exact hardware to run dual monitor. I plug a DVI (my main monitor) in and an HDMI that runs to a HD TV in another room. When I installed 16.04 the setup worked perfectly.

All I had to do was switch Audio Configuration to change sound from one to the other. Yesterday, I updated the system and suddenly, when the desktop is on the TV is black.

So I tried to change the configuration with the GUI Display Configuration Utility but could not fix it. If I leave the HDMI plugged in the Display configuration shows that both are recognized, but only one screen can be seen at a time.

Unplugging HDMI brings the regular monitor back, plugging the HDMI in switches the output to the TV. When I login, I can see the dual screen on both until I finish the boot, then it starts this behavior.

Comment: To add a little more detail.  If I plug both DVI Monitor and HDMI plugs into the GPU before booting, I can see both at the login screen. That is both are duplicated which is what I want.  Then I put my password in and the OS loading bar starts to cross. As soon as it gets to about 75% loaded the DVI monitor suddenly goes black and says "No Signal" I can still see it on the TV in the other room.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, different gpu version and using VGA and DVI. I am facing the same problem from the most recent update. I previously had both monitors working with the 4.4.0.22 kernel.

During startup see if there is a new kernel installed and try booting into an older one.

[How to change kernel at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621393/how-to-change-kernel-at-boot)

edit: also try this [Dell 3543 Kubuntu 16.04 can't get output to 2nd monitor on HDMI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763124/dell-3543-kubuntu-16-04-cant-get-output-to-2nd-monitor-on-hdmi) i haven't had a chance to give this solution a go

Comment: Changing the Kernel back had no effect.

Comment: the fix on the Dell 3543 thread didn't work either.